# How to refrence path from python script into yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a folder called data which is created from the following code

```
import shutil
import os

folderName = "..Data"
current_directory = os.getcwd()
final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory,folderName)
if os.path.exists(final_directory):
    shutil.rmtree(final_directory)
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
    os.makedirs(final_directory)
```

I want to get the path of this data folder and refrence it in a YAML file. I dont want to manually state the path as it will be run on azure using azure pipelines. is there a way i can get this path from  a python script into a YAML file? for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-data-assets?tabs=CLI trying to create a URI folder

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, you could use the [python SDK to create a uri_folder data asset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-data-assets?tabs=Python-SDK#create-a-uri_folder-data-asset).

> You can create a data asset in Azure Machine Learning using [the following] Python Code

Here is the sample provided in the docs, slightly tweaked for your case:

```py
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes
import shutil
import os

folderName = "..Data"
current_directory = os.getcwd()
final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory,folderName)
if os.path.exists(final_directory):
    shutil.rmtree(final_directory)
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
    os.makedirs(final_directory)

# Supported paths include:
# local: './<path>'
# blob:  'https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<path>'
# ADLS gen2: 'abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/'
# Datastore: 'azureml://datastores/<data_store_name>/paths/<path>'

my_data = Data(
    path=final_directory,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
    description="<description>",
    name="<name>",
    version='<version>'
)

ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)
```

---

**Update**

If yaml is the only option, note that it is possible to embed python code into a yaml file like so:

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/data.schema.json

# Supported paths include:
# local: ./<path>
# blob:  https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<path>
# ADLS gen2: abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/
# Datastore: azureml://datastores/<data_store_name>/paths/<path>
type: uri_folder
name: <name_of_data>
description: <description goes here>
path: |
    import os
    folderName = "..Data"
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory,folderName)
    print(final_directory)
```

Comment: if possible want to avoid using python SDK for this in my use case would be better if I can use azure cli for this. using azure pipelines

Comment: @muhammad, I have updated the answer, but please test and see.